# Is there a place to find TFS 2012 RC Build Controllers/Agents Status Errors

Tags: tfs, build

We recently upgraded our TFS 2010 to the TFS 2012 RC release.  Everything upgraded easily with the exception of our Builds.  Does anyone know where to find any logs that show why the build controllers/agents are running?

We have a Single Server configuration where TFS, SharePoint, SQL2008 R2, Build Controller, and Build Agent are all on the same box.

All of the new features appear to be working with the exception of builds.  When the build component is started, it initially shows the Controller and Agent as "Green Arrow" status, but after 30 seconds goes to the "Red Box" status.

[image: Build Config Status]

Then if you click the "Details" link to see what the error is, I receive a popup with a 500 error:
[image: Build Config Details Error]

Any help on how to diagnose or find error logs, etc. would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just fixed the problem.

We had added an additional port binding to the Web Site to make our Bug Tracker available via another port.  This created a scenerio where multiple bindings for the same protocol prevent the services from working correctly.

We added the following to the web.config file for the TFS site and everything started working again.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. Could you elaborate which "web.config" file you need to modify? Thanks.

Comment: For me the file to be modified was here:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Application Tier\Web Services

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the account that runs the controller/agent with a typical TFSService account.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the same problem, this is the path to the web.config file:

Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Version Control Proxy\Web Services